# How to use maybe to parse this string with a parser combinator library

Tags: javascript, parsing, haskell, parsec, parser-combinators

For learning purposes, I have implemented a small parser combinator library, which has a few parsers and combinators such as `char`, `maybe`, `sequence`, `many` etc.

I am having hard time figuring out how to emulate the following regex with my library, and how to make it fast.

Here is the regex:

```
/(a?){30}a{30}/
```

Here is the source:

```
const source = (new Array(30).fill('a')).join('')
```

Here is my solution (which does not work):

```
const parser = sequence(...[
  ...(new Array(30).fill(maybe(char('a')))),
  ...(new Array(30).fill(char('a'))),
])
```

Which expands to:

```
sequence(maybe(char('a')), maybe(char('a')), ..., char('a'), char('a'), ...)
```

My solution is a bit naive as the `maybe`s consume the input, leaving nothing but an unexpected end of input to the final parsers.

Questions:

Is there a solution to that problem using parser combinators? (I have seen parsec uses `try`/`lookahead`, but I can't figure out how it would work in this situation)

The perl version of this regex matches in 3 minutes (`perl -e '("a" x 30) =~ /^(a?){30}(a){30}$/;'`), while grep manages it in a few miliseconds, Is there an efficient way to solve it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's a horribly inefficient regex. One would write `/a{30,60}/`. You can write your own expression optimiser, or expect the user of your library to be sensible.

Comment: If your `maybe` parser does not support backtracking, that's your implementation's fault.

Comment: Well... what's your implementation of `maybe`, `char`, and `sequence`? Also, for regexen, you may like the classic [Regular Expression Matching Can Be Simple And Fast](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) which explains why perl is so slow and how to be as fast as grep.

Comment: Yes it does support backtracking, but it makes it slow @Bergi.

Comment: Thanks @DanielWagner, this looks amazing !